# change imagebutton Proportional to size device on android

Tags: android

I am develop xml with some image button,image buttons show properly in emulator but it Disorganization on

devices(for example galaxy fit)

As described in emulator https://www.dropbox.com/s/qeecp868ht61sck/emulator.jpg and galaxy fit https://www.dropbox.com/s/23r9tvtp0tcn7bs/fit.jpg

what change imagebutton Proportional to size device?

what can i do?

this is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main"
android:background="@drawable/backmain" >

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/btnfehrest"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
android:background="@null"
android:src="@drawable/fehrest" />

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/btndarbareh"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/btnfehrest"
android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
android:background="@null"
android:src="@drawable/darbareh" />

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/btnmahsulat"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btndarbareh"
android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
android:background="@null"
android:src="@drawable/mahsulat" />

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/btnkhoruj"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/btndarbareh"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:background="@null"
android:src="@drawable/khoruj" />

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/main"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all because you are using Relative Layout in your xml

Relative layout always maintains a relationship with other views in your xml either with Parent view or with child views.

so on small screen your FrameLayout with button image trying to fit in the screen as it maintaining the relationship with other views, that's why its overlaping.

Talking about giving the **suggestion** regarding this.

1) You can use **Linear Layout** with **scroll view**, ie if views gets out of screen you can see them  by scrolling down.

//If you don't wanna do this

2) You can create another xml in **layout-small** with same name.
   Example:

res> layout> **main.xml**

and

res> layout-small> **main.xml**

Second option will help you in creating multi support for different screen sizes.

Note: By Default layout-small folder is not present but you can create it.